# Tkinter GUI updating depending on serial connection

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, updating

Good afternoon thank you all who look at my issue,
I am building a script to do initial configuration on switches through console port, I can make a connection to the console port the issue comes when building a GUI in TKINTER.

I want the gui to connect through a specified some port when the button is pressed and when the connection is made make a light(using canvas) go green showing a successful connection went through.

My issue is getting the light to change to green and stay when a connection is made I have tried

- my initally also tried to use global then realized the window loop constantly set it back to red
- nested while loop--- breaks Tkinker
- importing a file I created called variableset which stores variable to set green but since it constantly has a new instance it just sets the variable in tinker back to red.

any help would be greatly appreciated

GUI CODE

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import connect
import variableset


setting = variableset.setting

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Network Wizard 1")
window.geometry('300x500')

# setting =tk.IntVar()

# setting.set(variableset.setting)

#serial port pick the right one 
serialportlabel = tk.Label(text="COM Number")
serialport = tk.Entry(width= 7)

serialportlabel.pack()
serialport.pack()

#color alerting!! red bad 

alert = Canvas(window, width=50, height=20)
alert.pack()
    
if setting == 0:
     a=alert.create_rectangle(5, 0, 50, 50, fill='red')

else: 
    a=alert.create_rectangle(5, 0, 50, 50, fill='green')


# #connection part woop woop 
connection = tk.Button(text="connect", command = lambda: bus())
connection.pack()


# #firmwarecheck
# firmwarecheck = tk.Button(text="Firmware check")
# firmwarecheck.pack()

# #firmware update
# firmwareupdate= tk.Button(text="Firmware update")
# firmwareupdate.pack()

# #software update
# software = tk.Button(text="software update")
# connect.pack()

# #vmlans
# vlanupdate = tk.Button(text="Vlanupdate")
# vlanupdate.pack()


# disconnect = tk.Button(text="disconnect")
# disconnect.pack()

# qut = tk.Button(text="quite")
# qut.pack()

def bus():
    
    global ser
    ser = connect.connect(serialport.get())
    
    global setting
    setting = variableset.initial
    
    

# def firmware(ser):

#     if ser.isOpen() == true :
        

    
window.mainloop()
```

Connect code

```
import serial 
import time
import sys

#connect 

def connect(com):
    ser = serial.Serial(
        
        port = com, #COM
        baudrate=9600, 
        parity='N',    
        stopbits=1,
        bytesize=8,
        timeout=8
        )
    
    ser.isOpen()
    
    
    print(ser.name)
    
    #set variables
    
    
    enter = str.encode('\r\n') #enter
    
    user = str.encode('admin@sytem\r\n') #default user name
    
    pwd = str.encode('\r\n') #defualt password
    
    qut = str.encode('quit\r')
    
    
    time.sleep(1.0)
    # ser.inWaiting()
    
    ser.write(enter) #promt login
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    ser.write(user) #enter user name
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    ser.write(pwd) #enter password
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    ser.write(enter)
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    ser.write(enter)
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    ser.write(str.encode("sytem\r\n"))
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    ser.write(qut)
    
    ser.write(qut)
    
    input_read = ser.read(500)
    input_read = input_read.decode("utf-8","ignore")
    
    print(input_read)
    
    ser.close()
    
    return ser
    
def write(ser):
    
    ser.write(str.encode(''+'\r\n'))


def disconnect(ser):
    
    ser.write(str.encode('quit\r\n'))
    time.sleep(.2)
    
    ser.write(str.encode('quit\r\n'))
    time.sleep(.2)
    
    ser.write(str.encode('quit\r\n'))
    time.sleep(.2)
    ser.close()
```

Variableset Code

```
global setting 

setting = 0 

def initial():
    
    global setting 
    setting = 1
    
    return setting 

def unset():
    
    global setting 
    setting = 0
    
    return setting
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your if-else statement only runs once, before the setting variable has been set, as far as we can tell. It's not in a loop or a function that gets called from somewhere else. What exactly is the problem you're having with the code that you posted? The issues you described seem to relate to a loop setting it back to red in a different version of the code.

In any event, I suspect that your problem is trying to use infinite loops to keep checking the setting, which prevents the tkinter mainloop() from running, and therefore blocks the GUI from updating. If so, the best method to fix it is probably to change your code for "check the setting and then change the color" into its own function, which gets called for the first time at the end of your connect function. Then, the end of the check setting function should schedule itself to be run after a time delay using the tkinter after() method, which is non-blocking (asnychronous) and allows the mainloop() to keep running. Alternative methods include a separate thread to run the check-setting code, or using the tkinter update() method, but after() is easiest.

Note that your sleep() functions in the connect code will also block the mainloop while they're running. I'm also not clear what you're trying to do with the variableset code; it appears to set the setting to 1 (aka green light) when you call initial(), regardless of the actual status on the serial port.